# Generate Combinations from Multiple Lists Including Null Columns using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, combinations, vba

I have two Sheets, Sheet1 has a bunch of information with 4 empty columns, and Sheet2 has 4 lists with a bunch of content under each.
Example:

List1: A, B, C
List2: D, E, F, G
List3: H, I, J, K, L, M
List4: N

I would like to fill in the empty columns in Sheet1 with all combinations of the lists, and duplicate the original Sheet1 content for each combination generated.
Example: (just a general idea, with no particular order)

ContentXYZ|(empty)|(empty)|(empty)|(empty)
ContentXYZ|A|(empty)|(empty)|(empty)
ContentXYZ|B|(empty)|(empty)|(empty)
...
ContentXYZ|(empty)|D|(empty)|(empty)
...
ContentXYZ|(empty)|(empty)|(empty)|N
...
ContentXYZ|B|F|(empty)|(empty)
...
ContentXYZ|(empty)|G|(empty)|N
...
ContentXYZ|(empty)|E|K|N
...
ContentXYZ|C|G|M|N

I've got the duplication part done and am stucked on the combinations part. Here's what I have so far, thanks in advance if anyone can help me complete the rest!

```
Sub DupSubGroup()

    b = 1
    d = 1
    f = 1
    h = 1

    Do

        Sheets(1).Activate
        Sheets(1).Range("A1:F1").Copy
        erow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets(1).Rows(erow)

    ...

    Loop While b <= Sheet2.Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlVisible).Rows.Count And d <=    Sheet2.Columns("D:D").SpecialCells(xlVisible).Rows.Count And f <= Sheet2.Columns("F:F").SpecialCells(xlVisible).Rows.Count And h <= Sheet2.Columns("H:H").SpecialCells(xlVisible).Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a cycle that creates all the permutations here is an example:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim List1 As Variant, List2 As Variant, List3 As Variant
  List1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
  List2 = Array(1, 2, 3)
  List3 = Array(True, False)

  Dim I1 As Integer, I2 As Integer, I3 As Integer, R As Integer
  R = 1
  For I1 = 0 To UBound(List1)
    For I2 = 0 To UBound(List2)
      For I3 = 0 To UBound(List3)
        Cells(R, 1) = List1(I1)
        Cells(R, 2) = List2(I2)
        Cells(R, 3) = List3(I3)
        R = R + 1
      Next I3
    Next I2
  Next I1
End Sub
```